# Adding active class to wordpress 3+ menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, superfish

I'm having problems with adding active class to wordpress menu. (If is home highlight home, if blog highlight blog and so on... )

I'm using superfish menu.

I have this in my functions.php

```
function me_register_menu() {
register_nav_menu('main-menu', __('Main Menu'));
}       

add_action( 'init', 'me_register_menu' );
```

And in my header, where my menu is

```
<?php 
if ( has_nav_menu ( 'main-menu' ) ) {
wp_nav_menu( array ( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' , 'container_class' => 'grid_7', 'container_id' => 'menu' , 'menu_class' => 'menu sf-menu') );
}
?>
```

I'd like to add .active class to my active menu. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with css. It's hard to say without seeing your page, but this should work:

```
/* Highlight using list element */
.menu-item a:active{
background:#999 !important;
color:#fff;
}

/* Highlight using link element */
.menu-item:active {
text-decoration:underline;
background:#666 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. It's not the problem with css. CSS is standard superfish menu.

Comment: Yeah, provide a link and I'll provide a css solution or offer a JS solution